# Simple random walk with biased probability

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

$Y_1,Y_2, Y_3, \cdots$ are independent and identically distributed R.V.s s.t. $$Pr (Y_i = 1) = p = 1 − Pr (Y_i = −1),$$ where $p∈(\frac 1 2,1)$. If $$S_n = Y_1+Y_2+Y_3 +\cdots+ Y_n,$$ prove that $$S_n \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} \infty. \quad n \to \infty.$$

I see this as a random walk problem related to markovs chain. But I am thinking of using law of large numbers, first  show that $E(Y_i)>0$ so that using the law, then $nE(Y_i)=S_n$ and since $n$ approaches $\infty$ then $S_n$ will also approaches $\infty$. If that is right, how would I make it more rigorous?

p.s. $E(Y_i)>0$ is easy to show ($p × 1-q × 1=p-q>0$).

Comment: The first step is to make a precise statement of the law of large numbers for the i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.  This is where "almost surely" language will be introduced. (This is also, essentially, the last step, in the sense that it immediately implies the result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the right idea, and maps directly to a rigorous argument. As you say, we have $E(Y)=2p-1>0,$ and it's also easy to see that $E(|Y|) < \infty,$ so the strong law of large numbers applies and gives us $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k \to E(Y)>0$ almost surely.

And then, along the same lines you suggest, $\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k\to \infty$ almost surely. (And in case it's not clear, it's all analysis from here on out, no more probability.) If you're looking to clinch that in a little more detail, note for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose an $N$ so that $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k - E(Y)\right| <\epsilon$ for all $n>N.$

Now let $M>0.$ We have $$ S_n> nE(Y)-n\epsilon$$ for any $n>N,$ so choose $\epsilon < E(Y)$ and then enlarge $N$ (if necessary) so that $N> \frac{M}{E(Y)-\epsilon}$ to make $n(E(Y)-\epsilon) >M$ for all $n>N.$

Comment: yea im looking for exactly this thank you but for the last statement enlargement, can you write it in a little more detail? im a little confused about why you enlarged it and what is M here preciely

Comment: I need to show that for any $M>0$ there is an $N$ such that $S_n>M$ for all $n>N.$ I first picked some $\epsilon < E(Y)$ and then I chose an $N'$ so that $S_n > n(E(Y)-\epsilon)$ for all $n>N'$ (which I can do since $S_n/n\to E(Y)$). However, what I really need is $S_n>M.$ I have $S_n > n(E(Y)-\epsilon)$ for $n>N'$ and can guarantee the RHS larger than $M$ for $n>N$ just by making $N> M/(E(Y)-\epsilon).$ So I can take $N >\max(N',M/(E(Y)-\epsilon)).$ It needs to be bigger than the first so the inequality holds, and bigger than the second so the RHS of the inequality is larger than $M$.

Comment: sorry im still a little confused, like why does this prove that it goes to infinity?

Comment: @TomWangzilin The first sentence of my comment is a definition of diverging to infinity. The rest of the comment/answer establishes the existence of the required $N$.

Comment: right, but Sn is the sum of RVs from X1 to Xn right? if we prove Sn>M, it means Sn>0 for n>N, but how does it show Sn $\to \infty$? or is Sn>m not Sn>0?

Comment: @TomWangzilin I use nothing about $S_n$ besides the fact that $S_n/n \to E(Y)>0.$ Proving that eventually $S_n>M$ holds for any $M$ is much stronger than $S_n>0.$ That and the rest makes no sense to me... are you confused about the definition of infinite limit?